# Plural of Sisters

Tags: grammatical-number

I have a picture of two of my daughters and their best friends who are also sisters. ie. two sets of sisters. What would be the correct pluralization of Sisters ?  or should I just give up with a single word to describe the picture?

Answer (score 5):

“Sisters” is already plural; there’s no way of ‘repluralizing’ it. Describe the picture using the phrase you have in the question, *“two sets of sisters”*.